# WPF Binding to get the property of the a DataGridCell

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, converters

The problem is described in the comment section of the WPF code below.

---

I basically want to bind to the `PropertyName` (not value) to which the cell is bound.

Instead of sending column name to my convertor, I want to bind with the property name of `Handle`, `Price`, `Quantity` instead of `HandleHeader`, `PriceHeader` and `QuantityHeader`. Right now my converter is getting `HandleHeader` instead of `header`. Co if my column name changes my code are no good.

That's why I want to use property name, so if somebody changes the grid column names my `dirtyConvertor` still works

```
<Window x:Class="dataGridColorsWithEvents.GridColorwithConvertor"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:y="clr-namespace:dataGridColorsWithEvents.Converters"
    Title="GridColorwithConvertor" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="DirtyStatus" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Resources>
            <y:isDirtyConverter x:Key="isDirtyConverter" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource isDirtyConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Dirty"></Binding>
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Column.Header"></Binding> 
                        <!-- here instead of binding by the column name, i want |  to bind with the property name(Handle,Price,Quantity instead of HandleHeader,PriceHeader and QuantityHeader
                                                                                |_______________
                                                                                                |
                                                                                                |
                                                                                               \  /
                                                                                                \/
                        For Eg.  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Handle2" Binding="{Binding Path=Handle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DirtyStatus}"/>
                        How can i access this property instead of column Header
                        -->
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TVM}"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            Name="dataGridCarHistResult" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="HandleHeader" Binding="{Binding Path=Handle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DirtyStatus}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dirty" Binding="{Binding Path=Dirty.Count}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DirtyStatus}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PriceHeader" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="QuantityHeader" Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DirtyStatus}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="TransmissionMethodHeader" Binding="{Binding Path=TransmissionMethod}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Change Quantity" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Button Content="Change Handle" Click="ButtonHandle_Click" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Content="Reload" Click="Button_Reload_Click" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

converter code

```
    public class isDirtyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;
        if (value.Length < 2)
            return false;
        if (value[0] == null || value[1] == null)
            return false;
        string columnName = "";
        IList dirtyColumns = value[0] as IList;
        columnName = value[1] as string;


        if (dirtyColumns == null || columnName == null)
            return false;
        if (dirtyColumns.Contains(columnName.ToUpper()))
            return true;

        return false;

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is confusing, some programmer is going to change a header text and you want to avoid that by changing a binding away from a value to a header? Something is amiss in the logic....

Comment: yes because right now my converter to decide whether a column is dirty or not depends on Column Header. I am adding my initial converter code. I think Funk's solution is going to work for me.